# Android - Facebook Connect, Check server side

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering how can I check if the user is connected to facebook on server side if connection comes from an Android APP.

Indeed, on my website I can easily check that in PHP when the request comes from a browser with :

```
// Try to get the user's id on Facebook
$userId = $this->facebook->getUser();

// If user is not yet authenticated, the id will be zero
if($userId == 0){
    // Generate a login url
    $data['url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email'));
    $response = array('status' => 'failed', 'error' => 'facebook_not_authentificated', 'url' => $data['url']);

    $data = json_encode($response);

    echo $data;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I call the url in my Android App, I do not pass this step and I get the JSON response `{'status' => 'failed', 'error' => 'facebook_not_authentificated', 'url' => '...' }`

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: viewed 7 times and not a clue ? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone need the answer i finally found out after many hours of research ...

You have to pass the token (token that you get into your android app), to the server and tell the server to use it :

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

To find out the token in your app :

```
Session.openActiveSession(InscriptionConnexionActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        System.out.println(user.getName() + " : connected");
                        $my_token = session.getAccessToken());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the user still authenticated in the device, you should use `Facebook Android SDK` on the device, not use the server side.

On the other hand, you can send the token you got from `Facebook` and send it to your server and check if it gives you a `Facebook User`.

Comment: I'm really interested in "you can send the token you got from Facebook and send it to your server and check if it gives you a Facebook User." it's exactly what i need. But how can i do that ?
Thx for your answer !

Comment: There is no need to do the request in your answer. When the user is logged in using Facebook, token is given to you in that callback.